# How to make a dataset with rows representing the no. of clusters while columns are two variables with different value for clusters

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, cluster-analysis

Im quiet confused.
I have 50 clusters each with a different size, and I have two variables "Year" and "Income level".
The data set I have right now has 10,000 rows where each row represents a single individual.
What I want to do is to form a new dataset from this dataframe where each row represents the number of clusters (50) and the columns be the two variables + the cluster variable. The problem is these two variables (that we call the study level covariates) do not have a unique value for clusters.
How would I put them in one cell for each cluster then?

```
X1<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4) #Clusters
X2<c(1,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2)  #Covariate1
X3<-c(1991,2001,2002,1998,2014,2015,1990,
2002,2004,2006,2006,2006,2005,2003,2003,2000) #Covariate2


data<-data.frame(X1,X2,X3)
```

My desire output should be something like this:

```
|Clusters|Covariet1|Covariate2|
|--------|---------|----------|
|1       | ?       |?         |
|2       | ?       |?         |
|3       | ?       |?         |
|4       | ?       |?         |
```

Meanening that instead of a data frame with 16 rows, a dataframe with 4 rows

Comment: not sure that I fully grasp your problem. If you want to combine two vector values, you could paste them together, e.g. data$combi <- paste(data$X2, "-", data$X3). This way you would have combined them and they hold hands re the index in X1.  Can you elaborate how you want to move your covariates to establish the desired rows?

Comment: @Ray I just updated the question to add a bit more clafirication

Comment: can you please fill in the expected values for covariate1 and covariate2 for your desired output table above ?

Comment: If you simply want to concatenate all the values of `X2`, `X3` for `X1` then use this - `library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,.(covariate1 =  paste0(X2, collapse = ',') , covariate2 =  paste0(X3, collapse = ',')),by= c('X1')]`

Comment: What do you intend to use the resulting data frame for? Is this for some kind of statistical analysis?

Comment: @mukund That is the issue! I have no idea what the values will be (not that I don't know the values because as I said, I dont know how R would put different values of X1 for cluster 1 but in 1 cell) or maybe Im confused because Im a newbie in r!

Comment: @coffeinjunky I am using propensity scores and for that, aside from the treatment allocation I also have the areas (clusters) where the treatment was randomized so for this one, I can not use the original dataset, I have to make a new one where instead of individuals, clusters are the rows

Comment: @mukund I ran the code you gave, but something doesn't feel right, how can I run a regression on these data that are together in one cell separating with "," ?

Comment: It is really your choice how to aggregate the data. Typically, you would use the average per cluster, but you can create multiple ones (min, max, certain quantiles, etc).

Comment: @coffeinjunky That makes sense! Thanks! after doing that, how can I then make that data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to aggreagate the data using the average of the covariate per cluster:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4),
                  X2 = c(1,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,2,2),
                  X3 = c(1991,2001,2002,1998,2014,2015,1990,2002,2004,2006,2006,2006,2005,2003,2003,2000)
                  )
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(X1) %>% summarise(mean_cov1 = mean(X2))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     X1 mean_cov1
* <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1       2  
2     2       1  
3     3       1.5
4     4       2
```

For the case you are working on, you have to decide what the most relevant aggreagation is. You can probably also create multiple at once.

Comment: Just one thing, Cov1 is actually an ordinal V. (or categorical, it could be), then the mean doesnt really make sense, the proportion?

Comment: StackOverflow is really more about programming, not so much about statistical modeling. You are right that, as said, you can and should think carefully about how you are going to aggregate the variables to the cluster-level, but it requires knowledge of your particular use case.

Comment: In either case, you can substitute 'mean' for anything else, or you can add anything else to get what you want. @Aura

Comment: Not really sure why you need to aggregate at all, though. If you adjust the variance-covariance matrix to be robust to clustering, there would be no need to throw away the intra-cluster variation. Maybe folks over at CrossValidated can advise on those bits better.

Comment: The statistical cosultant told me to! But Thanks! It seems logical and I could do what I wanted (except for the X2 where I am trying to say "use the most frequent category" and I have no idea how to put that there

Comment: In the `summarise` call, you can use other function than `mean`, such as `mode`, which gives you the most frequent value. You can also look into reshaping the data frame (pivot from long to wide) to cast the different values as new columns. With a bit of tinkering, you would get a whole range of dummy variables, but again, you would need to make sure this makes sense for your use case.